# How to send an automated email to the customers when product is added woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, email, e-commerce, plugin-mailchimp

I want to send email to the subscribers or customers when the new product is added to my woo commerce store
The email must have its price and any custom offer 
I have tried mailpoet plugin it allows me to send new post/product notification but it doesn't include prices